# Retrieving data from Firebase (web) not working

Tags: javascript, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I just got into Firebase and I´m trying to retrieve data from the realtime database, but I can't get anything to show up on the webpage.

This is what I got, before the JS I got the initialize Firebase code. (IF I delete the `val()` I receive `[object Object]` so something is at least working).

JS:

```
var heading = document.getElementById("head");

var firebaseHeadingRef = firebase.database().ref().child("Heading");

firebaseHeadingRef.on('value', function(datasnapshot) {
    heading.innerText = datasnapshot.val();
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="table_body"> <h1 id="head">Some Text</h1>
```

This is a screenshot from the database:

[image: 1]

I appreciate all help :)

Answer (score 1):

The Realtime Database is case sensitive. In your DB screenshot you have `Heading` but your JS code has `.child('heading')`. Try making those the same case and it should work. Note that you must also have appropriate [Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/) to allow access for unauthenticated users.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. I changed the h to upper case, but it didn't help. I have the security rules on both read and write set to true.

Answer (score 0):

I sort of faced a similar issue, everything was fine including the database rules but no data was being fetched.

**My solution**

My configuration containing the `apiKey` & `projectId` was missing the **databaseURL** portion, so I recopied the correct configuration & it worked.

**P.S**

Try checking your console for any warnings from Firebase